# Creating Dynamic number of GridViews

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need a bunch of GridViews to display on my page. I have a List of Lists of Section Objects called **dataList**, and each List in **dataList** should be bound to one of the GridViews.

I have this

```
List<List<Section>> dataList;
foreach (List<Section> sectionList in dataList)
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = sectionList
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

and my markup:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>
```

but when I load the page I can't see anything. How do I display all of the GridViews I created? Does the foreach loop I have successfully bind each GridView to the Lists of dataList? Thanks

Comment: if u r binding the gridview dynamically you dont need the gridview on the markup. in fact you need a placeholder there. the code you have written wont do any good to your cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your Gridview markup and Use PlaceHolder control to add dynamic Gridviews, Try this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
```

in C#

```
int i = 1;
foreach (List<Section> sectionList in dataList)
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    //generate dynamic id        
    gv.Id = "gv" + i; i++;
    gv.AutoGenerateColumns="true";
    gv.DataSource = sectionList
    gv.DataBind();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(gv);
}
```

Comment: The C# doesn't recognize the PlaceHolder I created in the Markup. Are there other parameters of the PlaceHolder object I'd need to set other than ID and runat?

Comment: above markup should work. What error do you get when you try to access ContentPlaceHolder?

Comment: I'm not working in SiteMaster, I'm working in a separate Results.aspx page, so I changed it to a PlaceHolder instead of a ContentPlaceHolder. I still cannot see the GridViews when I load the page though, despite having both the PlaceHolder and GridViews set so Visible = true